# Trouble proving through induction after establishing a basecase

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

What is the following sum?

$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + ... + \frac{1}{(n-1)n}$

Experiment, conjecture the value, and then prove it by induction.

I found the sum to be $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and established the base of n=2 being equal to $\frac 12$, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Also, use `\cdot` or `\times` for multiplication, not an $x$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry about that, I'll make note of it for next time. How does that help? Now I set that equal to $\frac{n-1}{n}$?

Comment: Note that your answer of $\frac{n-1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$.  Now, if you were to add the next term in the series written in the partial fraction decomposition I showed above, what happens?  This is a quintessential example of a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You established that it worked for $n=2$ (since $\frac1{1\cdot2}=\frac12=1-\frac1n$. This was the *base case*). Now assume that the statement is true for some $n=k$, so we have $\sum_{i=2}^k\frac1{i(i-1)}=1-\frac1k$ (this is the *inductive hypothesis*). So we have \begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}\frac1{i(i-1)}&=\frac1{(k+1)((k+1)-1)}+\sum_{i=2}^k\frac1{i(i-1)}\\
&\stackrel{IH}{=}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+1-\frac1k\\
&=\frac 1{k}-\frac1{k+1}+1-\frac 1k\\
&=1-\frac1{k+1}\\
\end{align}
In the first step, we take the term with $i=k+1$ out of the summation. Then the $\stackrel{IH}{=}$ sign indicates that, in that very step, we used our induction hypothesis. Now we proved that, if the statement is true for $k$, then also for $k+1$; and since it was true for $n=2$, it must be true for $3$, and this also for $4$, and for $5$, etc., and therefore it must be true for all natural numbers $n\geq 2$ (this is the principle of mathematical induction).

---

Alternatively, we can do this without induction by doing the following: \begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{i(i-1)}&=\sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac 1{i-1}-\frac1i\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=2}^n\frac1{i-1}\right)-\left(\sum_{i=2}^n\frac 1i\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i\right)-\left(\sum_{i=2}^n\frac1i\right)\\
&=\frac11-\frac1n+\sum_{i=2}^n\frac1i-\sum_{i=2}^n\frac1i\\
&=1-\frac1n
\end{align}

Comment: Two questions, where did you get $\frac {1}{(k+1)k}$ from and how does that actually prove anything?

Comment: We take the last term out of the summation, so $\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}f(i)=f(k+1)+\sum_{i=2}^kf(i)$. I'll edit my question in an attempt to clear things up

Answer (score 0):

By induction assume that:$\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 6 +\frac {1}{12}+\dots \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{n-1}{n}$

For $n+1:$

$\underbrace{\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 6 +\frac {1}{12}+\dots \frac{1}{n(n-1)}}_{=\frac{n-1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\stackrel{\color{red}?}{=}\frac{n}{n+1}$

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1+(n-1)(n-1)}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}=\boxed{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

As expected